# Custom query for custom post type not getting correct post ID

Tags: wp-query, functions, loop, query-posts

I have written a custom query here:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_status' => 'publish') );   ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tthememeta_video_oembed', true ) ); ?>
    <?php $embed = wp_oembed_get( $url ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

then when $URL is fetched, which I was expecting will give the video URL of that particular single post of the custom post type video is deviating.

It is giving the oldest video post $url irrespective of which post we are in?

the HTML where I am using it is here:

```
<div class="vframe">
        <iframe id="viframe" width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","https://www.youtube.com/embed/",$url); ?>" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is because you are overwriting the `$url` variable in your while loop. So the value of `$url` will be the last item of your query. I think you will need a foreach loop for this and save the data in an array.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with a bit of sample alternative code?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, do you know the current post ID where you write your HTML code?

Comment: Current post ID needs to be fetched dynamically isnt it?

Comment: That would work as well. But it will only return the first one. So if you have multiple, you will not get them all.

Comment: Please write your version sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95123/discussion-between-refilon-and-the-wp-novice).